# accessing current Location in google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have been looking at the google documentation  to get the  current location, but i am struggling to specify the location in the ViewDidLoad, as you can see i have set the Location fixed to Syndey Australia. In the google doc documentation when specifying the current location, they are using the "default location.coordinate" , i cannot access defaultLocation.coordinate in my code .

here is a link to the documenation : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/current-place-tutorial

this is the code inside the viewDidLoad

```
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyARsPfNs54hrUAC4yKtHeu2jXfGjeA0b-E")
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyARsPfNs54hrUAC4yKtHeu2jXfGjeA0b-E ")
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    // creating the marker //

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
```

This is my extenstion code

```
 extension MapsViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     let location : CLLocation = locations.last!
     print("Location:\(location)")
     let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: zoomLevel)
     if mapView.isHidden {
        mapView.isHidden = false
        mapView.camera = camera
      } 
      else {
        mapView.animate(to: camera)
    }

}
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .restricted:
        // display the map the default location
        mapView.isHidden = false
    case .denied :
        print("User denied access to location")
        mapView.isHidden = false
    case .notDetermined :
        print("Location status not deteremined")
    case .authorizedAlways  : fallthrough
    case . authorizedWhenInUse :
        print("Location status is OK")

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have configure your project properly.

Answer (score 2):

You have added wrong code in your method `searchLocationPressed`, Please update it as follow.

```
@IBAction func searchLocationPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let autocomplete = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocomplete.delegate = self
    self.present(autocomplete, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Your mistake is you are presenting `UISearchController` instead of `GMSAutocompleteViewController`.

Comment: thank you, i was wondering when the user types the location how do I move the marker to the location that they have specified

Comment: @Menphis, Happy to help you.

Comment: Do you know how i can have 2 search controller for start and end journey

Comment: do u understand what i mean

Comment: I didn't getting you, Could you please explain it by UI ? Please update image for what you want.

Comment: i have explain my error in the above code , can you help me please